# Display data in a TableView

Tags: java, javafx

Well, I changed the description, I think it would be clearer.

My application is divided into two parts (information on the right (1) and information on the left (2))
(2) - Here I have a table where I choose a contract.
(1) - The information that relates to the selected contract is displayed here, all shortcuts work correctly, but the information in the second table, which is in this part of the application (on the right), is not displayed, in this table I want to write down the links to the files that relate to the document which I chose on the left side
(Now while I use the type String, then I will do it under local links)

```
//I removed all unnecessary variables in my opinion that are displayed correctly.
public class MainData {

    private final List<StringProperty> nameLink;

    public MainData() {
        this.nameLink = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    public List<StringProperty> getNameLink() {
        return nameLink;
    }

    public List<StringProperty> setNameLink(StringProperty nameLink) {
        this.nameLink.add(nameLink);
        return getNameLink();
    }
}
```

```
public class MainController {
    private TableColumn<MainData, String> contractColumn;

    public MainController() {
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
          contractColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getNameLink());
    }
}
```

The problem is `Initialize`, lambda is waiting for the value ObservableValue, but I am passing `List<String>`, but if I change the value to `List<String>`, then the method `getNameLink` does not work for me how to fix it? How to make a wrapper?

Comment: @Slaw In the future, I want to enter data into TextField, pick up the value there and write it to the collection, and then write each value of the collection to a new row of the table.

Comment: @Slaw I use StringProperty as I read in the article that it is recommended to do in JavaFX

Comment: If you could better explain your data model, such as how `nameLink` relates to `MainData` and why there can be multiple "name links" per `MainData`, it would allow a more specific answer to your question. Currently, your `Callback` needs to return an `ObservableValue<String>` but is actually returning `List<StringProperty>`. However, I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Remember,  each instance of `MainData` will be a row in the `TableView`. Each property of `MainData` should typically correspond to a `TableColumn`. This means your data model has a `List` of `StringProperty` _for each row_.

Comment: @Slaw if you have time, see the changes, thank